# TinyMCE: Set <P> element as default wrapper

Tags: tinymce

I have this in the congfig file to prevent the `<p>` element

```
  force_br_newlines: true,
  force_p_newlines: false,
  forced_root_block: '',
```

I am able to insert `<br/>` when I hit the enter key but I also want `<p>` element in the form as default element and wrapped by whatever I enter.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Could you provide an example of the HTML output? You can always wrap everything into a p tag on save for example...

Comment: If you set the force_br_newlines option to true, Enter will produce a `<br />`, while Shift+Enter will produce a `<p>`